# Keep receiving warning for abnormally high response time

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, monitoring

I have made an account with Appfirst.com which monitors the linux. Since few days i keep receving email and i don't know what that means .

This is the email

> Over the last 5 minute(s) (from May 02
>   01:17 UTC to May 02 01:21 UTC),
>   connections to cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au
>   have had abnormally high response
>   time. Why?
>
> The root cause of the elevated
>   response time appears to be the result
>   of elevated File (I/O Write), Page
>   Faults, File (I/O Read), and Network
>   (Outbound Traffic) on

---

```
Server resource usage:
Server  Resource    Avg In Hour Before Event (May 02 00:17 UTC to May 02 01:16 UTC)     Avg In Last 5 Minutes (May 02 01:17 UTC to May 02 01:21 UTC)
cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au    File (I/O Write)        1,362,729 bytes 1,778,083 bytes
cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au    Page Faults         956 1,484
cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au    File (I/O Read)         1,695,684 bytes 2,256,621 bytes
cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au    Network (Outbound Traffic)  112,223 bytes   208,813 bytes
```

This is the other

```
Processes with largest increase for each resource:
Resource    Avg In Hour Before Event (May 02 00:17 UTC to May 02 01:16 UTC)     Avg In Last 5 Minutes (May 02 01:17 UTC to May 02 01:21 UTC)
File (I/O Write)
(process mysqld on cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au
                            234,534 bytes   632,968 bytes
Page Faults
(process httpd on cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au
                            was not running 246 (over 2 minutes)
File (I/O Read)
(process mysqld on cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au
                            489,812 bytes   954,373 bytes
Network (Outbound Traffic)
(process httpd on cpanel1.xxxxx.com.au
                            was not running   122,455 bytes (over 3 minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The gist is that your server is slow to respond because:

- MySQL is busy reading from disk
- MySQL is busy writing to disk
- Apache is busy reloading program data from disk
- Apache is busy sending data over the network

In other words, your server was too busy doing something several times over a 5 minute period to answer service requests in a reasonable amount of time.  It looks to me like your server is at or beyond capacity.  It's spending too much time reading and writing to disk and reloading parts of Apache into memory instead of what it's supposed to: answer service requests in a timely manner.

Is this a dedicated host or a shared host?  If it's shared, you should consider moving to dedicated.  If it's dedicated, you very likely need an improved server.  If you don't know if it's shared or dedicated, then it's shared.

Comment: i have vps server and there is only one site running on it . it has 768mb RAM . i have another VPS with 20 sites running. I haven't seen anything like this on that